# Is there a way to find out which table causes `duplicate entry for key PRIMARY`, without increasing hibernate log level?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I am using JPA2.0 (hibernate) in wildfly10, and at some point I get the message: `Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'.`

There are about 15 tables that get updated on the specific transaction. Is there a way to find out which table causes this error (e.g. from mysql server logs) without increasing the hibernate verbosity level?

Comment: Try setting <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>, or log the stack trace

Comment: "..without increasing the hibernate verbosity level"